# Inconsistent use of "Off-Topic"

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, scope

There was a question at the end of 2013 about the use of IntelliTrace with Windows Phone 8 apps, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20732290/how-can-i-use-intellitrace-in-wp8-apps).

[Today, I asked a very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24148865/is-intellitrace-supported-in-windows-phone-8-1) requesting an update with regard to Windows Phone 8.1 (a different platform) and received a very negative response.

Why is one question off topic and another is not? My understanding was that I could ask a question desiring a canonical response, especially when there are many representatives from the company in question (MSFT) on this forum. Further, I had done my research and the question had not been asked before (Windows Phone 8.1 is a very different platform than Windows Phone 8).

Was it simply that I asked for a link to a Microsoft reference? If so, then could the question not have been simply and easily modified to not ask for the reference?

Further, the reasons giving for closing were quite inconsistent (though all claimed "Off-Topic"). Half claimed I was asking for off-site resources, and the other half claimed I was asking for debugging help. The former is half-true, though I think there is an easier way to go about it than closing the question. The latter is not true. Just because I'm asking if something is available does not mean that I was asking for debugging help. Further, adding "I went throughout Visual Studio and couldn't figure out how to turn on IntelliTrace on Windows Phone" isn't really helpful in this case.

So, in the case that the only issue is that an asker mentions the possibility of a canonical, off-site answer (which is the preferred answer even if this is not asked for, as the previous question demonstrates), should the question simply be closed? Or modified to not request off-site reference?

Comment: How might that question be modified to make it on-topic?

Comment: It's not just the close reasons, it's also that the other was not closed. In fact, it was answered. The close reasons point to what about it could possibly be fixed though in order to make it a valid question for the site.

Comment: Your question is a search request.  We don't do those.  That the other question got a reasonable answer is quite the stroke of luck, since the OP's assertion that it might be a compatibility problem was a wild-ass guess.  Not much point in closing it now.

Comment: You attracted those who wish to impose their ego on you. The other poster got lucky.

Comment: @MrJack: Oh, stop it.  I dispute your assertion, and fart in your general direction.

Comment: @NateDiamond sometimes an older question escaped notice of users who can close questions.  Your question didn't.  It is unfortunate, but an existing question doesn't automatically make your question on-topic

Comment: I have searched for quite a while on it, and it is a very new platform. When asking the question, should I include all of the google searches I've done? What if someone else says "Oh, I was looking for that question earlier and found the answer to it as well. Here it is." Almost any question about the Windows Runtime is arguably a "search request", as most of the questions are plainly covered in the samples they provide. I don't think that's necessarily a reason for removal.

Comment: Don't ask for links to canonical resources.  That's what Google is for.

Comment: @RobertHarvey If that's the case, then it should be simple to remove that request in the question instead of closing it.

Comment: Why would we change the meaning of your question?  The community has been specifically discouraged from doing that.  Edits are for spelling errors, formatting, improving question clarity and the like, not putting words into other people's mouths.

Comment: @RobertHarvey somewhat of a side question, but the answer to the op's question is barely more than a link.  Shouldn't it be deleted?

Comment: We should change the question because the intended meaning was not meant to offend your sensibilities, but instead to get a possibly common question answered about a new platform. If the question is valid without two words in it, remove those two words. Instruct the offender of the offense so that they can learn about it for the future. Otherwise, I see no issue in reposting the question without the term "Canonical reference" in it.

Comment: @NateDiamond it is a heck of a lot more than 2 words... more than 50% of the text of your question would need to be removed.  If you want to edit it to remove the link request, then feel free to do so.  It will get put into the reopen queue and 3K users will be able to vote to reopen it if they think the edit improves the question

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/12/dont-be-afraid-to-use-the-science/

Comment: Or a diamond mod can go ahead and do it themselves

Comment: @NateDiamond your recent edits have made the question off-topic again.  You are noew asking about a 3rd party tool for debugging.

Comment: That's not 3rd party. That's a tool provided by Microsoft for x64, x86, and ARM processors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the question you asked, I believe that both close reasons were useful.

The first close reason, "Insufficient information to diagnose problem" is the community saying "Why are you asking?  Are you having a problem with Intellisense?  If so, explain the problem in detail with steps to reproduce it."

The second close reason, "Questions asking us to find or recommend..." is basically saying "We're here to provide our expertise, not show you where you can find that expertise somewhere else."